# AngularJS, Jasmine and issue writing spec tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Okay, so I have a seed setup and I have Jasmin Running (Thank you so much SoEzPz for the help).

it appears my spec's won't run, I tried and isolated spec and it ran with no issue but when I try to write one on a controller it errors.

here is the controller.

```
//This is the about function that is used in the About Module. 
'use strict';
app.controller('AboutController',// jshint ignore:line
    ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
      $scope.message = 'This is the about page message from the controller';
    }]);
```

a very basic controller

here is my test

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: com/modules/AboutController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var AboutController,
        scope;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            AboutController = $controller('AboutController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));
    it('It should show the page message', function () {
        expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("This is the about page message from the controller");
                                       });

    });
```

The spec returns this error

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at Suite.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8888/com/modules/about/aboutController_spec.js:5:16)
    at addSpecsToSuite (http://localhost:8888/:801:25)
    at Env.describe (http://localhost:8888/:771:7)
    at jasmineInterface.describe (http://localhost:8888/:3277:18)
    at http://localhost:8888/com/modules/about/aboutController_spec.js:3:1
```

am I missing something or is my spec written wrong ?

I am including the ngmock here is my Karma.conf file

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jul 28 2015 11:28:22 GMT-0400 (EDT)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      '../src/lib/js/angular/angular.min.js',
      '../src/lib/js/angular/angular-mocks.js',
      '../src/com/**/*.js',
      '../src/com/**/*_spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

Comment: Have you included ngMock? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

Comment: Try changing this part describe('Controller: com/modules/AboutController'... to  describe('AboutController',

Comment: I changed that and this is the error I get 
"message": "[ng:areq] Argument 'AboutController' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 1):

This was definitely deceptive, after playing around with the specs (thinking that the issue was in the actual specifications ) I found a test that ran fine, but still my other specs would not run, so what I did was I went back and took a hard look at my karma.conf file and while looking through some of the other examples I found I wasn't including enough in the way of bower components. so I added some more IE resources, cookies ect and low and behold all tests passed .

here is what I added under files for those who might be having the same issue

```
'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
        'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
        'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
        '../src/com/**/*.js',
        '../src/com/**/*_spec.js'
```